# Scrolling images shuffles and some images occurs many times

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio

I have a problem in Gridview, i.e. durring scrolling the images shuffle and some of them occur many times.

Here is my `getView()`:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View gridViewAndroid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridViewAndroid = new View(mContext);
            gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);
            TextView textViewAndroid = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_text);
            ImageView imageViewAndroid = (ImageView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_image);
            textViewAndroid.setText(gridViewString[i]);
            imageViewAndroid.setImageResource(gridViewImageId[i]);
        } else {
            gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;

        }

        return gridViewAndroid;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?